# Windows 10 Linux Subsystem: Can't type Pipe (|) Symbol in Bash

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, keyboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wanted to play around with the new Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu on Windows 10) but I can't type Pipe Character. I was playing around with the keyboard layout but nothing helped...
I use a standard German Keyboard and normally have to press **Alt Gr** + **<** to get a Pipe Symbol but nothing happens on the bash. Other Alt Gr Combinations like square brackets are working.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Greets
Jan

Comment: Check your bash keyboard layout? The files are in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\etc\default`

Comment: See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-to-asssign-keyboard-layouts-per-program/2cb3d17d-a507-477e-96a5-6dab302f7b76 to change the layout just for bash-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For US standard keyboard am able to type pipe character. Follow the below mentioned steps to change the keyboard layout

Add a keyboard layout:

1. Click the Start menu and select Settings.
2. Select Time & language.
3. Click Region & language in the left column.
4. Under Languages click the language you want as default (English US Keyboard) and click Set as default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks  - This one works for me. It's not an ideal solution for me, cause I now have to change the keyboard layout to english US when using the bash, but It's a beta right now, and hopefully it will be fixed soon :)

Answer (score 1):

From memory this is a known issue with the 23/Oct/2015 Windows Update for Windows 10 (TP) I believe, but I can  now, no longer find the post that I was reading. But it had something to do with wrong device drivers, that needed to be removed in Device Manager, then bounce the machine, and it should auto-magically install the correct driver..

I'm sorry I cannot be more helpful at this stage.. I'll keep looking for the article.. Until then, have you tried the on-screen keyboard? and have you just tried using left-ctrl and alt? That is a standard alternative for right-alt, but I suspect that the latter of the two at least, will not work. But the on-screen KB may.

Comment: Unfortunately not even the on screen keyboard will bring a pipe to the bash console :(

Comment: that is, indeed unfortunate. Sadly I've had precisely zero luck locating the kb article I was reading.. Just as a matter of interest, is it a Lenovo/IBM or possibly a Sony? Because I can remember that they were the machines having issues with their devices - it was the Synergy Driver, or similar. As I said earlier, find it in Device Manager (maybe back it up) and then delete the driver. Bounce your device, and you should be all good...

Also, just as a side note, I can't help but feel your offhand reference and depiction of the pipe symbol in the title, never ceases to be a little symbolic...

Comment: No it's not a Sony or Lenovo. It is a selfmade PC with no special vendor drivers installed I think. I also haven Synergy installed.
What works is setting the Keyboard Layout to englisch US liki Nithin suggested.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I did not even mention attempting to modify the Keyboard Layout and Region, because you had said in the initial post, that you had already tried this, and failed. Else it would have been somewhere near the top of my list.. anyway, pleased you got some resolution.

Comment: Ah, what I meaned in my initial post was I have changed the keyboard layout with dpkg-reconfigure in the bash. What worked was changing the layout in Windows :)